# Get date, hash and branch name of all branches

Tags: windows, git

The following command lists the last commit hash and branch name of all my local branches:

```
git show-ref --heads
```

Output:

```
<hash> <branch-1>
<hash> <branch-2>
...
<hash> <branch-n>
```

However, I want to see the date for each branch as well. The following command shows the date and hash but not the branch name of the last commit only on the current branch:

```
git log -1 --format="%ci %H"
```

Output:

```
<date> <hash>
```

How can I get results that are a combination of the two?

```
<date> <hash> <branch-1>
<date> <hash> <branch-2>
...
<date> <hash> <branch-n>
```

I'm using Windows 10 with no fancy command environments, just the basic command prompt.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to slightly adapt [this great GitHub post](https://gist.github.com/jasonrudolph/1810768) to get the following:

```
$ for branch in `git branch | grep -v HEAD`;do echo -e
      `git show --format="%ci %cr %H" $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r
```

**Output:**

```
2017-03-07 11:38:38 +0800 2 hours ago 87ed1306a1c06576043cd398097a1dc0ec456632 branch1
2017-03-07 02:50:06 +0000 3 hours ago 577fe106a9eb5763cbfd5bce87cfa9448ef52ca8 master
2017-03-07 02:50:06 +0000 3 hours ago 577fe106a9eb5763cbfd5bce87cfa9448ef52ca8 branch2
2017-03-03 17:07:05 +0800 4 days ago 419a23b246ad932c9659b70fded4b1362e92d884  branch3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as the "date of a branch".  Or, perhaps, there are too many things.  You will need to pick one.

Specifically, a branch name is just a name for some particular commit, with the name having some special properties (you can `git checkout` that name to get "on the branch", and once on the branch, you can `git commit` to make a new commit and update the name-to-hash-ID entry).

Commits themselves *do* have dates.  More precisely, they have *two* time stamps, one for the author and one for the committer.  Since a branch *name* like `master` or `develop` names one specific commit, you can retrieve either of these commit time-stamps and use that as a date.  But if we move the branch label to another different commit, this date will change, perhaps going backwards.  If two *different* branch names point to the *same* commit, both will necessarily have the same commit time-stamps.

Branches—in fact, almost *all* Git references: branch names, tag names, special names like `stash`, and even `HEAD` itself—also have *reflogs*, and each reflog entry records when and why something *changed* that reference:

```
8dbdf33 HEAD@{11}: reset: moving to HEAD^
70ac787 HEAD@{12}: cherry-pick: change default python path for FreeBSD
8dbdf33 HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from diff-merge-base to stash-exp
```

which is also:

```
8dbdf33 HEAD@{6 weeks ago}: reset: moving to HEAD^
70ac787 HEAD@{6 weeks ago}: cherry-pick: change default python path for FreeBSD
8dbdf33 HEAD@{6 weeks ago}: checkout: moving from diff-merge-base to stash-exp
```

These reflog entries do eventually expire, generally after 30 to 90 days (depending on whether the commit or other object named by the reflog entry is *reachable* from the current value of the reference), but until then, some reflog entry or entries might qualify as the "date of a branch".

[Tim Biegeleisen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42640813/1256452) gets you the committer time-stamp from the commit to which each branch-name points.  [The `git log` documentation, under the PRETTY FORMATS section](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_pretty_formats), includes, e.g.:

> *%ci*: committer date, ISO 8601-like format

For a robust script, I'd recommend replacing:

```
for branch in `git branch | grep -v HEAD`
```

with:

```
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads)
```

though (or something similar—more work can be done directly in `for-each-ref`, for instance).